# raw printing - graphics mode

Tags: linux, debian, printing, cups, printer

I have been playing with a 9-bit Epson LX-300 dot-matrix printer under Debian.

So far was able to:

- send plain text to the printer:  `echo 'Los comandos para configurar > /dev/usb/lp0`
- change the printer's behavior through ESC/POS commands: `echo -en '\x1B\x2D\x01' > /dev/usb/lp0` (add underline)
- Add it to cups: `lpadmin -p LX-300 -v serial:/dev/usb/lp0` and print through it: `lpr -P LX-300 -o raw text.txt`

Now, I'd like to use the printer's **graphics mode** capability. 
How to send a graphics file to the printer and get it to print as graphic and not plain text?

Comment: `\x1B^` ? http://www.bitrade.by/support/Epson%20LX-300+%20Service%20Manual.pdf *9  pin bit image*

Comment: Have a look at using postscript and a postscript to LX300 driver. Many graphics file (wether bitmap oriented or vector oriented) can be converted to postscript. I find it more interesting to know how to send a graphics file to the printer as text (and get a meaningful result).

Comment: To expand on Anthon's comment, GhostScript can output PostScript files on a 9-pin Epson dot-matrix printer; try `man gs` for details.

Comment: Thanks Anthon and Stephen. Converting the image to postscript and instructing lp to print `p -d LX-300 jake.ps` works! Yet the image is distorted with a sort of echo of it happening at its right. Any thoughts?

Comment: correction: `lp -d LX-300 jake.ps`

Comment: using gs also works `gs -sDEVICE=epson -r60x72 -sOutputFile=/dev/usb/lp0 lolipop.ps`